# Power supply CE compliancy requirements

Tags: power-supply, safety, ce, regulations, compliance

I'm dealing with an electrical equipment which should be compliant to the CE low voltage directive (LVD), following the EN60950 standard. 
The equipment is connected to the mains (220V) through an external power supply which provides DC power at 12V. The equipment has a metal casing which is not connected to ground.
Is it a requirement to use a Class II double insulated power supply. Or would a standard Class I power supply be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event of a failure with a Class I your metal enclosure could potentially be dangerous to touch. So you have to ground it. The class I requires to be connected to a properly grounded outlet.

The class II doesn't need the grounded outlet and do not require your enclosure to be grounded.

Comment: why could the enclosure become dangerous? The power supply is external (physically separated from the enclosure) and the enclosure itself is completely isolated from the DC power (both +12 and ground)

Comment: IF the supply (Class I) fails you risk the DC side to be lethal without the grounding of the equipment enclosure. The Class II tries to mitigate the risk of the mains going to the equipment by utilizing more insulation. Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes